# PHPUnit: Error: Unsupported operand types (when trying to expose a protected method using a subclass)

Tags: php, phpunit

I tried to use a subclass to expose a protected method for testing but get the title error when doing so.

```
Error: Unsupported operand types

<path removed>/SeedDataLoader.php:99
<path removed>/tests/SeedDataLoaderTest.php:15
<path removed>/tests/SeedDataLoaderTest.php:55
```

Here is the subclass which is in SeedDataLoaderTest.php

```
class PublicSeedDataLoader extends SeedDataLoader {
  protected $instance;

  public function __construct() {     
    $this->instance = new SeedDataLoader();
  }

  public function buildInsertQuery(array $dataList): string {
    return $this->instance->buildInsertQuery($dataList); // line 15 error
  }      
}
```

The invocation from the testing class

```
class SeedDataLoaderTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {    
  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();       
  }

  public function testBuildInsertQuery() {
    $publicSeedDataLoader = new PublicSeedDataLoader();

    $inputList = [ <bunch of nested arrays removed> ];

    $expectedString = "<long string removed>";        
    $result = $publicSeedDataLoader->buildInsertQuery($inputList); // line 55 error

    $this->assertEquals($expectedString, $result);
  }
}
```

And finally in case it's relevant, the underlying protected method in the parent class:

```
  protected function buildInsertQuery(array $dataList) : string {
    $values = '';

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($dataList); $i++) {
  // setup the final lined modifier
  $endingMark = ',';
  if ($i = sizeof($dataList - 1)) { // line 99 error
    $endingMark = ';';
  }

      $values .= " <string removed> ";
    }

    return $values;
  }
```

Does anyone see what throws this error?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by removing subtraction on the array above, changing the line to this:

```
($i = sizeof($dataList - 1))
```